# WPF Popup permanently displays in Visual Studio design-time

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, popup, design-time, cider

I’ve met strange behaviour for WPF design-time in Visual Studio 2010: after an instance of the Popup class was created, and I switched the code tab in Visual Studio to a different file, the Popup still remains on the screen!

[image]

I have a piece of code, which allows to reproduce this, but I am not sure if I should paste it here (it's not so short), so maybe I'll just give a link to it: [here](http://codeyourself.net/wpf-popup-permanently-displays-in-visual-studio-design-time/).

Comment: I've seen the same bug in VS2008.

Answer (score 2):

For unknown reasons beyond mere mortals' comprehension, Microsoft has decided this is the default behavior of the `Popup` class in WPF. You have to implement the "hiding" logic yourself. I suggest handling the `Window.LocationChanged`, `Window.Activated` and `Window.Deactivated` events of the Window containing the Popup and close it yourself.

Edit: To clarify myself, the Window events you need to handle are the events of the window that contains the Popup's `PlacementTarget` element. Usually when you create a popup, you set it relative to some element contained in an application's Window (similar to how the tooltips work). If this is your case, then my solution is correct, but I forgot to mention this point about the PlacementTarget.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but it seems, like there is no Parent of type Window (nor parent of parent) at design-time in WPF. Apparently the parents are instances of some internal classes like MS.Internal.Designer.ZoomableViewPresenter for example. But you pointed me in good direction (and for this I vote +1), so I will try to examine events of those instances. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for edit. I iterated in design-time all parents of my `PlacementTarget` (slider in my example, see [link](http://codeyourself.net/wpf-popup-permanently-displays-in-visual-studio-design-time/) ), but the problem is, that in design-time, Visual Studio is not creating application's `Window` (even if xaml defines exactly `Window` type), but instead of this, it's child is instantiated in MS.Internal.Designer.ZoomableViewPresenter (and other non-`Window` classes, which don't have suitable events). Of course in run-time it's different - there is `Window` as a parent, like it should be.

Answer (score 1):

In your code behind; you can simple check this boolean:

```
DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this);
```

"this" represent the object containing the popup. For example the Window.

If true you can say:

```
myPopUp.IsOpen = false;
```

For Store Apps/WinRT:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled
```